# How do I overlay an image over a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a canvas that shows matrix binary code raining down. I would like to add an image over the canvas in question

This is what I have

```
<div class="rain">
            <canvas id="Matrix"></canvas>
             <div class ="imgclass">
                <img class="imgclass" src="assets/image.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JavaScript for the canvas

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('Matrix');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const latin = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const nums = '0123456789';

const alphabet = latin + nums;

const fontSize = 16;
const columns = canvas.width/fontSize;

const rainDrops = [];

for( let x = 0; x < columns; x++ ) {
    rainDrops[x] = 1;
}

const draw = () => {
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    context.fillStyle = '#0F0';
    context.font = fontSize + 'px monospace';

    for(let i = 0; i < rainDrops.length; i++)
    {
        const text = alphabet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length));
        context.fillText(text, i*fontSize, rainDrops[i]*fontSize);
        
        if(rainDrops[i]*fontSize > canvas.height && Math.random() > 0.975){
            rainDrops[i] = 0;
        }
        rainDrops[i]++;
    }
};

setInterval(draw, 30);
```

and the CSS:

```
.rain {
    background: black;
    height: 40%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
    background-image: url("assets/img.jpg");
}
```

Right now the image in question appears below the canvas as opposed to on the canvas (ie. in the middle).

Comment: Do you really want the image to be overlayed on the canvas? This will hide the effect. My guess is that you want the raining text to overlay the image. When I run the code provided with an actual image it seems to work momentarily, but the image "fades" to black fairly quickly. This is not easy to fix by "overlaying" the image onto the canvas. Your algorithm adds a shade of black to the canvas on each draw. While this makes for a cool looking effect, it masks the underlying image over time. To fix this your rain animation algorithm needs to be more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to wrap the canvas in a div and set the div background to your image.

Here I am applying my CRT effect to your canvas.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('Matrix');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const latin = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const nums = '0123456789';

const alphabet = latin + nums;

const fontSize = 16;
const columns = canvas.width / fontSize;

const rainDrops = [];

for (let x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
  rainDrops[x] = 1;
}

const draw = () => {
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.fillStyle = '#0F0';
  context.font = fontSize + 'px monospace';

  for (let i = 0; i < rainDrops.length; i++) {
    const text = alphabet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length));
    context.fillText(text, i * fontSize, rainDrops[i] * fontSize);

    if (rainDrops[i] * fontSize > canvas.height && Math.random() > 0.975) {
      rainDrops[i] = 0;
    }
    rainDrops[i]++;
  }
};

setInterval(draw, 30);
```

```css
@keyframes flicker {
  50% {
    top: -3px;
  }
}

.crt::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAGCAYAAADkOT91AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAqSURBVBhXYxTiF68WZ2TQeqLE8o3hicEbJgY0gFNgHRBvBuK9hLQwMAAAF54HHx1Goh0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
  background-size: 4px, 6px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  pointer-events: none;
  filter: contrast(50%);
  animation: flicker 0.08s step-end infinite;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="crt">
  <canvas id="Matrix"></canvas>
</div>
```